# Tabbed content opening multiple instances and disappearing at time's

Tags: html, css

I have this tabbed content thats disappearing and opening different instances of it self Its just a very basic tabbing method i got from w3schools I cant really understand why it would do that. 
Ill be adding the site just so it can be tested

```
 <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">

                <div class="panel-body mg-top-s">
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1default">
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-12">
                                <img class="we-tab-img" src="<?php echo home_url();?>/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/we-do-img-1.png">
                            </div>
                                <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-12 tab-text">
                                <h3>RESEARCH</h3>
                                <p>Before starting any task, we begin with research into to current trends, our
                                    clients brand’s and the competitive playing field</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade row" id="tab2default">

                            <div class="col-md-3 col-12">
                                <img class="we-tab-img" src="<?php echo home_url();?>/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/we-do-img-1.png">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-12 tab-text">
                                <h3>RESEARCH</h3>
                                <p>Before starting any task, we begin with research into to current trends, our
                                    clients brand’s and the competitive playing field</p>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3default">Default 3</div>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab4default">Default 4</div>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab5default">Default 5</div>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab6default">Default 6</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1default" data-toggle="tab">01</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tab2default" data-toggle="tab">02</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tab3default" data-toggle="tab">03</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tab4default" data-toggle="tab">04</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tab5default" data-toggle="tab">05</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tab6default" data-toggle="tab">06</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

```
.nav-tabs{
    background: none!important;
    border: none!important;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.nav-tabs>li.active>a{
    color: black!important;
    background-color: #C9132A!important;
    border: solid 2px #C9132A!important;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
.nav>li>a:hover{
    color: black!important;
    background-color: #C9132A!important;
    border: solid 2px #C9132A!important;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
.nav-tabs li a{
    font-size:20px;
    color:#585669;
    font-family: 'Raleway SemiBold', arial!important;
}
```

Here's the site if you want to test it out

[The Site](http://azipit.co.za/lionremaster/)

Its on the home page under WE DO

Answer (score 1):

Add class `show` on `<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1default">`.
See this [pen](https://codepen.io/rajibmehedihasan/pen/XWmBRvB) as a reference

Comment: Still having the same result :( Mind having a look on the site link I posted I did what you mentioned just have a look and confirm that its still acting up

Comment: it seems everything is fine. Did you connect bootstrap as well as jquery??

Comment: I did yes, Els most of the site wont work make sure u click between them alot like 8-10 times atleast Thats usually when it breaks for me

Comment: Copy pasted your Codepen Same thing.

Answer (score 0):

It's a odd one but Its my lazy Naming convention's when I gave everything a more "Unique ID" like 1/2/3/4/5/6 It started working perfectly

So:

```
  <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">

                <div class="panel-body mg-top-s">
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="1">
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-12">
                                <img class="we-tab-img" src="<?php echo home_url();?>/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/we-do-img-1.png">
                            </div>
                                <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-12 tab-text">
                                <h3>RESEARCH</h3>
                                <p>Before starting any task, we begin with research into to current trends, our
                                    clients brand’s and the competitive playing field</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade row" id="2">

                            <div class="col-md-3 col-12">
                                <img class="we-tab-img" src="<?php echo home_url();?>/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/we-do-img-1.png">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-12 tab-text">
                                <h3>RESEARCH</h3>
                                <p>Before starting any task, we begin with research into to current trends, our
                                    clients brand’s and the competitive playing field</p>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="3">Default 3</div>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="4">Default 4</div>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="5">Default 5</div>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="6">Default 6</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#1" data-toggle="tab">01</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#2" data-toggle="tab">02</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#3" data-toggle="tab">03</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#4" data-toggle="tab">04</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#5" data-toggle="tab">05</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#6" data-toggle="tab">06</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```